# Why is template parameter a reference in this case?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, forwarding-reference

Stubled upon a weird behaviour when playing with std::forward. Here is a small example:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename A>
void func(A&&)
{
    std::cout
        << std::is_pointer<A>::value
        << std::is_lvalue_reference<A>::value
        << std::is_rvalue_reference<A>::value
        << std::endl;
    using B = typename std::remove_reference<A>::type;
    std::cout
        << std::is_pointer<B>::value
        << std::is_lvalue_reference<B>::value
        << std::is_rvalue_reference<B>::value
        << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int* p = nullptr;
    func(p);
}
```

It prints `010` and `100`, meaning `A` is a reference and not a pointer, while `std::remove_reference<A>` is a pointer as expected.

But why is it so? I thought that `A` would be a pointer and `A&&` a reference inside the function body. Also, what types are `A&` and `A&&` if this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) works; when being passed an lvalue, the template parameter `A` will be deduced as an lvalue-reference. For this case, it's `int*&`, i.e. an lvalue-reference to pointer. (After reference collapsing, the function parameter's type would be `int*&` too.)

When being passed an rvalue, `A` will be deduced as non-reference type. For example if you pass an rvalue with type `int*`, `A` will be deduced as `int*`. (Then the function parameter's type would be `int*&&`.)

Comment: This is a piece of syntax I didn't even know. It becomes even more clear with a function like `template <typename A> func (A&& a1, A& a2, A a3);`, which it seems you can never call